# Mac Grey/White Screen of Death

Tags: macos, mac, osx-snow-leopard

The other night I updated my iTunes to the latest version (through Software Update) when I came to turn on my computer I was greeted with the dreaded white screen of death.

I use an early 2008 iMac 24".

I've tried the basic things, unplugging/turning off accessories, trying to boot from the install disk, reseting pram, etc, etc.

Still no luck and no change what-so-ever.

All I've been able to ascertain that my keyboard still works (by ejecting).

I should point out that I did recently replace my Hard drive with a Western Digital Black 500GB (though the computer is well out of warrenty) and I'm a little concerned that the problem could be the screen.

**Update (18/05/10):** *I've been told that I could be getting the White/Grey screen of death because the optical flex cable is damaged (aparently this is common).  Apparently the Optical Drive is part of the POST sequence, and an inability to read the drive can result in failure for the system to move on to other bootable volumes.  More info [here](http://arstechnica.com/civis/viewtopic.php?f=19&t=80115&p=2155397#p2155397).
I will disable the optical drive and see if that works.*

Comment: Well, if you think it's the screen, how about plugging in an external CRT or projector and seeing if that works? That'll tell you for sure...

Comment: *I'm a little concerned that the problem could be the screen* -- then what is the white screen of death you're referring to? Apparently not [a Kernel panic](http://support.apple.com/kb/HT1392) screen?

Comment: No, I didn't get a Kernal Panic.  Everything was working fine before I shut the iMac down.

Comment: If only so simple!  Unfortunatley I'm not in a position to do that at the moment.

Comment: Ah, my reference to the kernel panic was wrong; I thought a white screen of death was always supposed to show something, but [apparently not](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/White_Screen_of_Death). Still: is it really just a white screen, or is there *some* indication on it, like [Gray screen appears during startup](http://support.apple.com/kb/TS2570)?

Comment: No spare monitors lying around? Well at least you get points for being tidy ;)

Comment: It goes straight to the white screen even when trying to boot from the install disc, etc.

Comment: @marcus, I assume a Mac would boot even if it knows the screen or video card is somehow faulty. Hence: any chance you can SSH into it? Or get it to beep when pressing the volume control keys, or incorrect key combinations? (Like maybe Command-Z to undo, while there's nothing to undo really.) Or if it's password-protected: type an invalid password?

Comment: Do you still have the old hard disk around, and does it still hold the  OS?

Comment: I'm afraid not, do you it could be the hard drive? When the old one failed it made a lot of clicking noises and allowed me to boot to the install disc easily.

Comment: Have you attempted to run the Apple Hardware Tests? While you said that you tried booting from the install media - I believe your model also allows you to hold the D key at boot to get into AHT without a disc.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem on my MBP13 late 2009. What I did was booting from a bootable backup that I had on a external USB harddrive. Then I could change the primary boot device to my DVD-drive and reinstall Leopard (and start the upgrade process to Lion yay!).

Note: you should use the install discs that came with your mac, not any upgrade discs.

You cloud also try booting from the install disc, I know you said that it didn't work but please try. I had to wait for 5 minutes once.